# How to disable pin security from Samsing Tab 2

Tags: security, lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

I have a Samsung tab2, and have added screen pin lock on my Tab few days back as I was going out. Now I don't want to use pin lock as security, but I am not able to disable it. I am going to

```
setting --> security --> screen lock
```

After entering my pin my options are to disable includes last the option **None**.

What should I do to remove the screen lock pin??

Comment: Which ROM are you using? Stock or Custom?

Comment: Under some circumstances Android forces you to have a PIN or password. This happens, e.g. if you install a custom trusted certificate. Therefore I would check Security settings and there the storage options if user certs are installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, I installed my own certificate which even on removing was some where present don't know where so ultimately I cleared up every thing and again tried to remove pin and it got removed.

Proper way would be **settings-->security-->clear credential** Clear credentials is last option under security heading.

And now u can change your pin  **setting-->security-->screen lock-->swipe/none** whatever you feel comfortable with.

Enjoy :D

Comment: Not working for me.. I've Samsung S2

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Settings**--> **Profiles** .
In the profile settings at the bottom is an entry for "**System settings**-->**Lock screen mode**".
You can choose several settings, one of which is disable.
You can disable Lock Screen by "**disable**" option or you can remove PIN by "**insecure lock screen**" option.

**OR**

Turned off the screen, turned it back on and clicked on Forgot in the right down corner. Give Google password and it will change Lock method automatically back to slide.

Just try it.

Comment: Thanx, but that's what I added that, None option is disable in my case!!!

Comment: If you already set a PIN , then there should be a prompt to enter PIN if you tried to change it. Was there any prompt pop-up when you tried so?

Comment: yup. As I mentioned in the question after entering pin NONE option is disable.

Comment: Answer edited with solution.

Answer (score -2):

I also messed around with the lock screen, and only when i cleared all credentials it came to remove the pin protection.